error occured during install laravel 8 via composer
when I write a installer command
-->composer global require laravel/installer

this type of error occurred

Failed to download doctrine/inflector from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Now trying to download from source

I don't know how to solve this problem
please give me solution for this error
